Rank in SQL special case
Write Hive SQL query to get the output from the input shown below.
I am trying to add rank column which is ordered by event_ts. But if there is same item_id for any consecutive rows, they should get the same rank. Partition by item_id will not work here as it will rank each partition window starting from 1. But I want the rank to monotonically increase.

NOTE: dense_rank() will not solve this

Input:



event_ts
item_id




T1
AA


T2
XX


T3
CC


T4
CC


T5
CC


T6
AA



Output:



event_ts
item_id
rank




T1
AA
1


T2
XX
2


T3
CC
3


T4
CC
3


T5
CC
3


T6
AA
4




Have you tried the window function called dense_rank()?

@dfundako dense_rank() will not work here. Please go through the question.

Will you ever restart your rank column because you have a new series of event_ts such as Z1, Z2, etc. Or is the rank column just 1 thru n without restarting?

@Isolated You can assume this is the only input data for now. Once I have the solution for this, I will be able to modify it for other cases.

I'm thinking that lag or lead might lead to a solution.

@Isolated: something like: https://dbfiddle.uk/c_2jsZ9V But the last row (for T6) is incorrect.

@Isolated Yes, using lag we can get item_id of previous row. If that matches with item_id of current row, then keep the same rank as previous row. Otherwise increment it. But this has to be done sequentially starting from the 1st row. But I’m not aware of any such option in hive.

This should give you what you're looking for. It will keep the same rank if the row above has the same value, then will continue incrementally ranking.
Select
event_ts,
item_id,
sum(inc) over(order by event_ts) as rank_order
from (
  select *,
    case when lag(item_id) over (order by event_ts) = item_id
      then 0 else 1 end as inc   
  from table1
) table2

table1



event_ts
item_id




T1
AA


T2
XX


T3
CC


T4
CC


T5
CC


T6
AA



Results



event_ts
item_id
rank_order




T1
AA
1


T2
XX
2


T3
CC
3


T4
CC
3


T5
CC
3


T6
AA
4



